# Unable to deselect redistributables in InstlallShield (where did the checkbox go)?

Tags: installshield, installscript-msi, installshield-2013

I have an InstallShield 2013 InstallScript MSI project and I changed the view on the Redistributable tap and now I can no longer see the checkbox that allows you to deselect a redistributable. Unfortunately I don't remember what I did to change the view.How can I get back to that view so that I can change what's supposed to be redistributed with our product?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the  **[Checked]**   button in your screenshot (at the top of the redistributables list)?
Grab that button with the left mouse button and drag it to the column list. You should see red arrows appear. Drop the button, and it will then add the checkboxes as a new column wherever you dropped it.
[image: IS2013 Column Fix]